# C# dynamic compilation of string and .cs file

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-construction, dynamic, compilation

I'm working on a website where a user can implement a C# code solution to a problem in a browser text area and submit it.  The server will then compile that code together with a predefined interface I provide on the server.  Think of it as a strategy design pattern; I provide a strategy interface and users implement it.  So I need to compile a string and a predefined *.cs file together at run-time.  Here's the code I have now that compiles only the string portion:

```
CodeDomProvider codeProvider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");

CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();
parameters.OutputAssembly = "CodeOutputTest.dll";   // need to name this dynamically.  where to store it?
parameters.GenerateExecutable = false;
parameters.IncludeDebugInformation = false;

CompilerResults results = codeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, request.Code);
```

Users would submit something like this:

```
public class UserClass : IStrategy
{
     public string ExecuteSolution(string input)
     {
         // user code
     }
}
```

Security concerns aside (that's a heavy question for another day)...how can I compile this together with my predefined interface *.cs file?  Or is there a better way of handling this?

Thanks!

Comment: Unless you have exceptionally good reason to trust all of your users, I would strongly suggest that you consider security concerns first.  There's not a lot of point in determining *how* to solve the problem if you determine that there's no possible way to do it safely.

Comment: For security issue, I would suggest running in its own AppDomain.  This would also allow you to 'unload' the assembly once its build.  Depending on your volume, you could end up with hundreds/thousands/more assemblies held in memory.

Comment: @TheSean, I'm not sure just running the code in another AppDomain adds much security. Running it in another AppDomain *under partial trust* does.

Comment: Yes, security is definitely a concern here.  But with a little research I think I should be able to run the code as a user with little to no privileges whatsoever.  I noticed some properties on the CompilerParameters object, such as the Evidence or UserToken properties, that might aid in restricting the access granted to the code.

Comment: hey jturinetti, did you manage to do this? I need to implement something really similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`CodeDomProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.codedomprovider.compileassemblyfromsource.aspx) is defined as

```
public virtual CompilerResults CompileAssemblyFromSource(
    CompilerParameters options, params string[] sources)
```

That means you can compile one assembly from multiple source files. Something like:

```
codeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, request.Code, otherCode);
```

Another (possibly better) option is to reference already compiled assembly that contains the code you need. You can do this using [`CompilerParameters.ReferencedAssemblies`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.compilerparameters.referencedassemblies.aspx):

```
parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("SomeLibrary.dll");
```

Comment: Pre-compile you interface!  Also consider using CompilerParameters.GenerateInMemory = true, if  you don't care about the DLL file.

Comment: The interface is precompiled :)  It's in a separate project/DLL in my service layer.  I will probably generate the compilation results in memory as well...thanks for that.