# Windows Forms: Is it possible to insert .cs files in runtime?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, artificial-intelligence

We organize artifical intelligence contest where people can write ai for our game engine written in C# Windows Forms. Competitors write ai codes for our game and we insert this codes into our game manually but this requires effort and I think there is a way to let people insert their .cs files in runtime. How can we design this architecture please someone help us. Thanks in advance and sorry for my english.

Note: .cs files include artifical intelligence logic.

Comment: dynamic compilation, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725817/c-sharp-dynamic-compilation-of-string-and-cs-file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe use the strategy pattern.  Have the contestants implement an entry point via an interface.  Your Game shell can then scan all assembly files in a given folder and find all types that implement the entry point interface.

**Update:**

To get you started I do a similar thing here (see method `ScanAssembliesForHostTypes`): http://shuttle.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/ba9750ca1f7a#Shuttle.Core%2fsource%2fShuttle.Core.Host%2fHostFactory.cs